# Application not displaying navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, xcode

i have an application with sqlite3 database. In console i can see that application can read data from it, but, i can't get it on a screen. Its just a white screen, i don't know why. There is my code:
AppDelegate file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface FailedBanksAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *_navController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;

@end
```

And .m part:

```
#import "FailedBanksAppDelegate.h"
#import "FailedBankDatabase.h"
#import "FailedBankInfo.h"

@implementation FailedBanksAppDelegate

@synthesize navController = _navController;
@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    NSArray *failedBankInfos = [FailedBankDatabase database].failedBankInfos;
    for (FailedBankInfo *info in failedBankInfos) 
    {
        NSLog(@"%d: %@, %@, %@", info.uniqueId, info.name, info.city, info.state);
    }


    [self.window  addSubview:_navController.view];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    self.navController = nil;
}

@end
```

I follow that tutorial,  http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-making-our-app, and did exactly things author did, but, is just a white screen, even without rows! And yes, i did connect outlets..

In console i can see this:
2012-03-18 11:15:56.186 Doctorina[3091:f803] 230: First Alliance Bank & Trust Co., Manchester, NH
2012-03-18 11:15:56.186 Doctorina[3091:f803] 231: National State Bank of Metropolis, Metropolis, IL
2012-03-18 11:15:56.187 Doctorina[3091:f803] 232:

Right before i wrote this i got message in console - application expected a root view controller, then i change window for self.window, and message disappear. Still it was a white screen..

I add that code, like u said:

```
UITableViewController *rootController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FailedBanksListViewController" bundle:nil];

    _navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
```

But now it says - program receive a message SIGABRT.

There is my FailedBanksListViewController files:

.h file is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FailedBanksListViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSArray *_failedBankInfos;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *failedBankInfos;

@end
```

.m file is:

```
#import "FailedBanksListViewController.h"
#import "FailedBankDatabase.h"
#import "FailedBankInfo.h"


@implementation FailedBanksListViewController

@synthesize failedBankInfos = _failedBankInfos;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.failedBankInfos = [FailedBankDatabase database].failedBankInfos;
    self.title = @"Failed Banks";

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_failedBankInfos count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = 
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    FailedBankInfo *info = [_failedBankInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = info.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", 
                                 info.city, info.state];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing the navigation controller.

```
(...)
for (FailedBankInfo *info in failedBankInfos) 
{
    NSLog(@"%d: %@, %@, %@", info.uniqueId, info.name, info.city, info.state);
}
UIViewController *rootController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNibFile" bundle:nil];

_navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];

[self.window  addSubview:_navController.view];
(...)
```

Comment: Thanks i will try to do something, but as i said i was just followed tutorial, which was write on early version of Xcode

Comment: It does not matter which Xcode version it is, there must be some bug in the tutorial or you missed some steps. You must create the view for the navigation controller either in the interface builder or programatically as i pointed you, but this didnt change from versions

Comment: I can't answer my own thread, so i edited main thread , please have a look

Comment: Do you have a nib named FailedBanksListViewController?

Comment: no, just controller class. Im not very keen in coding, but I'm learning. In tutorial i was browsing, author use initWIthNibName method only when he display detail view (there was a xib file for it), but not for rows of elements.

Comment: no worries. I supposed you already had a nib, but otherwise you can just call `UIViewController *rootController = [[UIViewController alloc] init]` but then you will have to add all your controls programatically. Either you can create a nib file by adding a new User Interface -> View (this will crete a xib element) in your project, then use interface builder to create your view.

Answer (score 0):

you are initializing and assigning the navigation controller till that part is correct..but u didn't add any root view controller to navigation controller...
see the below code

//Instantiation of navigation controller 
    UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewControllerObj];

```
//Navigation controller is asssigned as RootView Controller
self.window.rootViewController=nav;
```

That's it make sure you have properly allocated and intialized the viewControllerObj

Then in viewControlleObj class

you can easily navigate another app using the following syntax.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcObj1 animated:YES];

in vcObj1 u can return to previous view using

POpViewCOtnroller method of self.navigationController.

You might think if we have to again create a navigationcotnroller in the view controller in order to push another view controller...

No self.navigationcotnroller means the the navigationcontroller instance u created on appdelegate...